# Play!, how to create a route with a "_escaped_fragment_" parameter?

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I'm working with Play! scala 2.4 and I'm trying to create a route with a "_escaped_fragment_" parameter but I can't do that in my routes.conf file. 
Indeed,

```
GET /  @application.Application.indexOrSnapshot(_escaped_fragment_: Option[String])
```

returns a compilation error.

So, I tried to add a sird route like that (as explained in the documentation):

```
class SirdComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
  lazy val router = Router.from {
    case GET(p"/?_escaped_fragment_=$path") => Action {
      Results.Ok(s"Hello $path")
    }
  }
}
```

but I don't understand how I can use it, and in particular where have I to place this snippet of code.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: In the `routes` file, try putting a space between the last underscore and the colon: "\_escaped_fragment_ : Option[String]"

Comment: and snake-cased naming is not very usual in Play for such case

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco I had already tried this but it doesn't work...

Comment: @cchantep It doesn't depend on me, it's for google bots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes parser is a bit more strict in this case than the scala parser. 
Wrapping the parameter in backticks should work:

```
GET /  @application.Application.indexOrSnapshot(`_escaped_fragment_`: Option[String])
```

Comment: thank you, but I get this compilation error: `)' expected but ``'

Comment: Seems to work for me, can you post the full compilation error and the exact line that you used on the routes file? Maybe there's an extra backtick in there?

Comment: error: Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompilationException: Compilation error[`)' expected but ``' found]
route: GET / @application.Application.indexOrSnapshot(`_escaped_fragment_`: Option[String])

Comment: I tested it on play 2.5, maybe the version you're using doesn't have this fix? https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4693